# Modifying cacerts at runtime

Tags: certificate-authority, java, container, kubernetes

I have an containerized JVM application (multiple actually) running on kubernetes, which needs to trust additional custom/private CAs (which are not known beforehand, the application will be deployed in multiple unrelated data-centers that have their own PKI).

The `cacerts` in the base image are not writable at runtime.

Currently I see these options:

1. do not provide an option to modify cacerts, force the DCs to manage & inject their own `cacert` files via container volumes.
2. make `cacerts` file writeable at runtime and modify cacerts in entrypoint
3. do not use JDK TLS - set truststore at "client" level (e.g. CXF)
4. ...?

Under the assumption the DCs will not run JVM apps only, they will not like to manage cacerts themselves, because `cacerts` is specific to JVM and they then potentially need to do that for *every* technology. Thus I do not really like that option.

The second option seems to be a quite pragmatic one - but I suspect that making the `cacerts` writable at runtime is a bad practice because an attacker could modify configuration s/he should not be able to.

The third option has it's limitations and intricacies because you need to make each each and every client configurable. (In case of CXF for example fetching the initial WSDL file does *not* seem to covered by CXF but by the JVM...) But this means if your client is *not* (properly) configurable this does not work.

Thus I am back at option 2.

My questions would be:

Is it a bad practice to have `cacerts` writeable at runtime?

Is there an option I missed that allows injecting (arbitrary) additional CAs into `cacerts` without making it writeable at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a combination of an init container and an `emptyDir` volume which is `readOnly: true` in the application container?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: cacerts
          image: cacerts-importer
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cacerts
              mountPath: /media/cacerts
            - name: cacert-imports
              mountPath: /media/cacert-imports
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: app:v1
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cacerts
              mountPath: /media/cacerts
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: cacerts
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: cacert-imports
          configMap:
            name: cacert-imports
```

Comment: not sure why the yaml does not get highlighted, but maybe that's just on my side.